# Absolute URL routing with sammy.js

Tags: routes, sammy.js

I have a URL that's absolute:

```
<a href="https://circleci.com/docs/configuration">configuration</a>
```

I use Sammy.js for routing, but it won't route it. However, it's happy to route the relative version of the same URL:

```
<a href="/docs/configuration">configuration</a>
```

How can I make sammy route the absolute version in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use a hash in your `href`, i.e. `href="#ESPN"`

Then capture the route with Sammy and use the `location.assign` method to load the new URL or retrieve the document:

```
Sammy(function () {
    /* Top-bar navigation requests
    */
    this.get("#:view", function () {
        switch (this.params.view) {              
            case "ESPN":
                location.assign("http://www.espn.com")
                break;    
        };
    });

    /* Reporting Excel requests
    */
    this.get("#Reporting/Excel/:type/:audience/:unitID/:departmentID", function () {
        location.assign("Report/Excel?" +
            "Type=" + this.params.type + "&" +
            "Audience=" + this.params.audience + "&" +
            "UnitID=" + this.params.unitID + "&" +
            "DepartmentID=" + this.params.departmentID
        );
    });
}).run();
```